# SoftHSM cannot get certificate

Tags: java, keystore, softhsm

In SoftHsm (v2.4.0) I noticed that you cannot extract a self-signed certificate if you don't have its corresponding private key in the same token. I generated the certificate with OpenSSL, and then imported it using **softhsm2-util --import**.

I am using Java to interact with SoftHSM, and calling *KeyStore.getCertificate(label)* returns **null** if the private key is not present.
Is this a bug or a normal cryptography thing?
I tried to look online but didn't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behavior you are observing is not caused by SoftHSM but most likely by JAVA's `SunPKCS11` provider. Its implementation is usually documented in *"PKCS#11 reference guide"*:

- [JDK 7 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
- [JDK 8 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
- [JDK 9 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm)
- [JDK 10 PKCS#11 Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm)

Pick a correct guide for your JAVA version and take a look at *"KeyStore requirements"* chapter.  You'll find your answer there:

> 5. Any private key or certificate object not part of a private key entry or trusted certificate entry is ignored.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!